# What it costs to use Task.Delay()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am thinking on using C# async\await in MMO game server with event-driven logic. Let's assume there are thousands of entities doing some work with known durations. So I would like to invoke `Time.Delay()` for every of my game objects. (This is an opposit approach to common infinite loop with some `Update()` call for every game object.)

Does anybody knows how is `Task.Delay()` implemented?
Is it using timers? Is it heavy on system resources?

Is it okay to spawn thousands of simultaneous `Task.Delay()` invocations?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Because `Thread.Sleep` isn't `async`?

Comment: And Task.Delay is? That doesn't make sense. If I want to delay a thread, I want it NOW, not spawning another thread to tell one to halt.

Comment: @Cole The point is to make a thread wait some time before resuming. The point isn't to delay a thread.

Comment: @ColeJohnson The await/async stuff causes a call to `Task.Delay()` to appear to return immediately from the code that calls it, and the code following the delay will resume after the delay is over. It's non-blocking (as long as the method calling it is itself `async`).

Comment: @MatthewWatson - how is that any different from a Sleep() call?  I don't understand :(

Comment: @It'sNotALie. because calling `Thread.Sleep` with argument other than 0 or 1 is always a big design problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is implemented as follows:

```
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  //error checking
  Task.DelayPromise delayPromise = new Task.DelayPromise(cancellationToken);
  if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
    delayPromise.Registration = cancellationToken.InternalRegisterWithoutEC((Action<object>) (state => ((Task.DelayPromise) state).Complete()), (object) delayPromise);
  if (millisecondsDelay != -1)
  {
    delayPromise.Timer = new Timer((TimerCallback) (state => ((Task.DelayPromise) state).Complete()), (object) delayPromise, millisecondsDelay, -1);
    delayPromise.Timer.KeepRootedWhileScheduled();
  }
  return (Task) delayPromise;
}
```

It definitely uses timers. They're used in a class called `DelayPromise`. Here's the implementation for that:

```
private sealed class DelayPromise : Task<VoidTaskResult>
{
  internal readonly CancellationToken Token;
  internal CancellationTokenRegistration Registration;
  internal Timer Timer;

  internal DelayPromise(CancellationToken token)
  {
    this.Token = token;
  }

  internal void Complete()
  {
    if (!(this.Token.IsCancellationRequested ? this.TrySetCanceled(this.Token) : this.TrySetResult(new VoidTaskResult())))
      return;
    if (this.Timer != null)
      this.Timer.Dispose();
    this.Registration.Dispose();
  }
}
```

It does use a timer, but it doesn't seem like a worry to me. The timer just calls back to the complete method, and what that does is check if it's canceled, if so cancel it, else just return a result. It seems fine to me.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that it creates a new timer object for each Delay.  I would have thought it would use some delta-queue with one timer.

Comment: As said in MSDN documentation: "System.Threading.Timer is a simple, lightweight timer that uses callback methods and is served by threadpool threads." To me "lightweightness" and "threadpool threads" seem to be incompatible concepts.

Comment: It is indeed a little strange that, when there is a choice between Sleep() and a timer call, some developers seem to insist that extra inter-thread comms and context-changes is the preferred solution.

Comment: I believe that the actual (unmanaged) implementation does use a delta-queue. Still, if you have many, many `Delay` calls, you'll be creating a lot of garbage and it wouldn't be the most efficient solution. If your "thousands of entities" are doing several things a second, I'd consider alternatives.

Comment: @StephenCleary I don't see anything calling any unmanaged code in the decompiled code in this answer. So, where would that unmanaged implementation come from? Are you saying that the C# compiler has special support for `Task.Delay()`? Or that CLR does?

Comment: I meant the `System.Timers.Timer` implementation, part of the CLR. And I'm going from memory after looking it up years ago - I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, now I am defenitely not going to use Task.Delay for such sort of purposes. It is not a problem to write my own delayed tasks manager. Just was interested. Thx everyone!

Comment: The .NET Timer implementation wraps the Win32 timer queue, which is a delta-queue that fires events on the thread pool.  More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core `Task.Delay` is implemented via `TimerQueue`. It does not create a new `Timer` every time. From what I can see from [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Timer.cs,47) it instead it creates N "queues", where N is the number of CPU cores. And then it uses 1 (one) timer for each queue.

This is more lightweight than the  .NET *Framework* approach, but still there's a sh*tload of code executed every time you call a `Task.Delay`. I wish there was a better way.

P.S. Just adding a more up to date version for google-searchers.