# High performance async monitoring tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a couple of hundred devices and I need to check their status every 5 seconds.

The API I'm using contains a blocking function that calls a dll and returns a status of a single device

```
string status = ReadStatus(int deviceID); // waits here until the status is returned
```

The above function usually returns the status in a couple of ms, but there will be situations where I might not get the status back for a second or more! Or even worse, one device might not respond at all.

I therefore need to introduce a form of asynchronicity to make sure that one device that doesn't respond doesn't impend all the others being monitored.

My current approach is as following

```
// triggers every 5 sec
public MonitorDevices_ElapsedInterval(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
{       
   foreach (var device in lstDevices) // several hundred devices in the list
   {
       var task = device.ReadStatusAsync(device.ID, cts.Token);
       tasks.Add(task);
    }

   // await all tasks finished, or timeout after 4900ms
   await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(tasks), Task.Delay(4900, cts.Token));
   cts.Cancel();

   var devicesThatResponded = tasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        .Select(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        .ToList();
}
```

And below in the Device class

```
public async Task ReadStatusAsync(int deviceID, CancellationToken tk)
{  
    await Task.Delay(50, tk);   
    // calls the dll to return the status. Blocks until the status is return     
    Status = ReadStatus(deviceID);
}
```

I'm having several problems with my code

1. the foreach loops **fires a couple of hundred tasks simultaneously**, with the callback from the Task.Delay being served by a thread from the thread pool, each task taking a couple of ms.

I see this as a big potential bottleneck. Are there any better approaches?

This might be similar to what Stephen Cleary commented here, but he didn't provide an alternative [What it costs to use Task.Delay()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378548/what-it-costs-to-use-task-delay)

2. In case ReadStatus fails to return, I'm trying to use a cancellation token to cancel the thread that sits there waiting for the response... This doesn't seem to work.

   await Task.Delay(50, tk)
   Thread.Sleep(100000) // simulate the device not responding

I still have about 20 Worker Threads alive (even though I was expecting cts.Cancel() to kill them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the foreach loops fires a couple of hundred tasks simultaneously

Since `ReadStatus` is synchronous (I'm assuming you can't change this), and since each one needs to be independent because they can block the calling thread, then you *have* to have hundreds of tasks. That's already the most efficient way.

> Are there any better approaches?

If *each* device should be read every 5 seconds, then each device having its own timer would probably be better. After a few cycles, they should "even out".

> await Task.Delay(50, tk);

I do not recommend using `Task.Delay` to "trampoline" non-async code. If you wish to run code on the thread pool, just wrap it in a `Task.Run`:

```
foreach (var device in lstDevices) // several hundred devices in the list
{
  var task = Task.Run(() => device.ReadStatus(device.ID, cts.Token));
  tasks.Add(task);
}
```

> I'm trying to use a cancellation token to cancel the thread that sit there waiting for the response... This doesn't seem to work.

Cancellation tokens do not kill threads. If `ReadStatus` observes its cancellation token, then it should cancel; if not, then there isn't much you can do about it.

Thread pool threads *should* not be terminated; this reduces thread churn when the timer next fires.

Comment: Thank you. If I were to have a ReadStatusAsync in the API, would my current implementation with Task.Delay be valid?

And spot on with the usage of a separate timer for each device, should have thought about that!

Comment: @RaduTomy: I don't see the need for `Task.Delay`. If it's asynchronous, call it and `await`; if it's synchronous (and you need a separate thread), then call it via `Task.Run`. If you go with a timer per device (as recommended), you shouldn't need `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this Microsoft example page of a cancellation token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191552(v=vs.110).aspx), the `doWork` method is checking for cancellation on each loop. So, the loop has to start again to cancel out. In your case, when you simulate a long task, it never checks for cancellation at all when it's running.

From [*How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx), it's saying at the end : "So, can you cancel non-cancelable operations? No.  Can you cancel waits on non-cancelable operations?  Sure… just be very careful when you do.". So it answers that we can't cancel it out.

What I would suggest is to use threads with a ThreadPool, you take the starting time of each one and you have an higher priority thread that looks if others bypass their maximum allowed time. If so, `Thread.Interrupt()`.