# Call function to be done after X minutes, but don't wait until it's done to return something from main function

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to write a function which does something, then before return something it triggers a function to be done after 30 minutes. I do not want to wait 30 minutes until another function will be done to return something from main function, how to do that?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateEvent(FormDataCollection formData)
{
     //do something
     asyncFunction(30) - function to be done after 30 minutes (this function will probably have to have Thread.Sleep or something, not sure)
     return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Is it possible in any way? I do not want to wait `asyncFunction` to be done to return `HttpStatusCode`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create a "run-once" time delayed function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904636/best-way-to-create-a-run-once-time-delayed-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: look into [scheduled tasks] and particularly into [quartz.net](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/quartz.net/info)